# Multiple containers in Codnvy

Tags: codenvy

Can you have multiple containers in Codenvy, like a server container and a mysql container?

Or is Codennvy an enriched container itself - just embeddet with different frameworks installed incl. ide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple containers - any you want as defined in a Docker Compose file. If you sign up for an account and create a workspace with the "Java-MySQL" stack you'll get a sample app using an app server and database.